# Symfony : bug while the handlerequest?

Tags: forms, symfony

Here is a mission entity object (part of it) :

```
class Mission {
   /**
   * @var \DateTime
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="datedebmission", type="date", nullable=true)
   */
  private $datedebmission;

  /**
   * @var \DateTime
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="datefinmission", type="date", nullable=true)
   */
  private $datefinmission;

  function getDatedebmission(): \DateTime {
    $date = $this->datedebmission;

    if(is_null($date)) {
        $date = new \DateTime();
        $date->setTime(8, 0);
        $this->datedebmission = $date;
    }

    return $date;
  }

  function getDatefinmission(): \DateTime {
    $date = $this->datefinmission;

    if(is_null($date)) {
        $date = new \DateTime();
        $date->setTime(12, 0);
        $this->datefinmission = $date;
    }

    return $date;
  }

  function setDatedebmission(\DateTime $datedebmission) {
    $this->datedebmission = $datedebmission;
  }

  function setDatefinmission(\DateTime $datefinmission) {
    $this->datefinmission = $datefinmission;
  }
}
```

in the form view I wanted to seperate Date and Time. So I added 4 fields in the Mission class (with no annotation concerning the database of course). here they are :

```
/**
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      message = "Cette valeur est obligatoire."
 * )
 */
private $datedebmissiondate;

 /**
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      message = "Cette valeur est obligatoire."
 * )
 */
private $datedebmissiontime;

 /**
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      message = "Cette valeur est obligatoire."
 * )
 */
private $datefinmissiondate;

 /**
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      message = "Cette valeur est obligatoire."
 * )
 */
private $datefinmissiontime;

function getDatedebmissiondate() {
    return $this->getDatedebmission();
}

function getDatedebmissiontime() {
    return $this->getDatedebmission()->format('H:i');
}

function getDatefinmissiondate() {
    return $this->getDatefinmission();
}

function getDatefinmissiontime() {
    return $this->getDatefinmission()->format('H:i');
}

function setDatedebmissiondate(\DateTime $datedebmissiondate) {
    $this->datedebmissiondate = $datedebmissiondate;
    $this->setDatedebmission($datedebmissiondate);
}

function setDatedebmissiontime(String $datedebmissiontime) {
    $datedebmission = $this->getDatedebmission();
    $time = explode(':', $datedebmissiontime);

    if(count($time) !== 2) {
        throw new Exception('heure incorrect dans datedebmissiontime');
    } else {
        $this->datedebmissiontime = $datedebmissiontime;
        $datedebmission->setTime($time[0], $time[1]);
        $this->setDatedebmission($datedebmission);
    }   
}

function setDatefinmissiondate($datefinmissiondate) {
    $this->datefinmissiondate = $datefinmissiondate;
}

function setDatefinmissiontime(String $datefinmissiontime) {
    $datefinmission = $this->getDatefinmission();
    $time = explode(':', $datefinmissiontime);

    if(count($time) !== 2) {
        throw new Exception('heure incorrect dans datefinmissiontime');
    } else {
        $this->datefinmissiontime = $datefinmissiontime;
        $datefinmission->setTime($time[0], $time[1]);
        $this->setDatefinmission($datefinmission);
    }   
}
```

Now I can add use my new Fields in the MissionType class :

```
$builder->add('datedebmissiondate', DateType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Date de début mission',
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        'attr' => array(
            'no_results_text' => 'JJ/MM/AAAA'
        )
    ));

    $builder->add('datedebmissiontime', TextType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Heure de début mission',
        'attr' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Heure:Minutes'
        )
    ));

    $builder->add('datefinmissiondate', DateType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Date de fin mission',
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        'attr' => array(
            'no_results_text' => 'JJ/MM/AAAA'
        )
    ));

    $builder->add('datefinmissiontime', TextType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Heure de fin mission',
        'attr' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Heure:Minutes'
        )
    ));
```

The twig now :

```
 {{ form_row(form_mission.datedebmissiondate) }}
 {{ form_row(form_mission.datefinmissiondate) }}
 {{ form_row(form_mission.datedebmissiontime) }}
 {{ form_row(form_mission.datefinmissiontime) }}
```

Everything is displayed like I expect it to be with date of the day and the 2 hours 08:00 and 12:00 in datedebmissiontime and datefinmissiontime

Submitting the form, I handle the request in the controller:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Debugging, I checked the request : everything is there.

This action should call all the set methods of the different parameters in the Request.
Indeed, set methods are called..all of them BUT the last one datefinmissiontime.

The result is that my mission Object got after handlerequest with :

```
$mission = $form->getData()
```

has everything but the datefinmissiontime field which is null : my form is not valid.

Going back to the view it displays the error message under the `datefinmissiontime` field shown with 12:00 as default value.

IMPORTANT: If I change the value (with 15:00 for example), now it works and all the set methods are called.

Does somebody know why the set method of this field is not called while `handleRequest` call if I did not change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `setDatefinmissiondate` is missing the important line

```
$this->setDatefinmission($datefinmissiondate);
```

This is why, even when the date changes, the underlying datetime doesn't change and remains `null`.

The `setDetafinmissiontime` isn't called, because the form component AFAIK doesn't call the setter if the value hasn't changed, which from the point of the property accessor (which the form component uses) it hasn't.

Adding the "missing" line should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much... I was searching for hours and did not see it... the power of the new eyes.